# meaning of a KEY in CREATE TABLE statment in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with mysql .

I have checked the CREATE table statement , and I saw there a KEY word

```
| pickupspc | CREATE TABLE `pickupspc` (
  `McId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Slot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FromTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ToTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Head` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nozzle` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FeederID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompName` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompID` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PickUps` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Errors` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ErrorCode` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ndx_PickupSPC` (`McId`,`Slot`,`FromTime`,`ToTime`,`Head`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

But what is the meaning of it ?
It's not like a PRIMARY KEY right ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is simply a synonym for `INDEX`.  It creates an index with the name `ndx_PickupSPC` on the columns specified in parenthesis.

See the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) syntax for more information.

Answer (score 6):

It's just a non-unique index. [From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html)

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can
>   also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This
>   was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

Answer (score 2):

**Key** and **index** are the same. The word `Key` in the table creation is used to create an index, which enables faster performance.

In the above code, Key `ndx_PickupSPC` means that it is creating an index by the name `ndx_PickupSPC` on the columns mentioned in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It's an INDEX on the table. Indexes enable fast lookups for specific queries which check the values of the columns the index is built on. The example uses a compound key.

They are a bit similar to the indexes you find at the end of the books. You can quickly find an entry with the index without searching through the whole book. Databases typically use B-Trees for indexes.